# Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path in Api Gataway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have trouble with accessing S3 via Api Gataway. I subscribe the following template:

```
 /s3:
        get:
          produces:
            - application/json
          parameters:
            - name: "key"
              in: "query"
              required: false
              type: "string"
          responses:
            "200":
              description: 200 response
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            credentials:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - ApiRole
                - Arn
            requestParameters:
              - integration.request.path.key: "method.request.querystring.key"

            uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:s3:path/{key}"
            consumes:
                - application/json
            produces:
                - application/json
            responses:
              default:
                statusCode: '200'
            passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
            httpMethod: GET
            type: aws
```

But when I check the work:

[image]

I get an error:

`Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path at index 35: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{key}
Thu Dec 13 22:46:03 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 500`

Probably my querystring is not overridden in the integration request. But I can't figure out how to do it right.

Comment: > Expand **URL Path Parameters**. Then, choose **Add path** and do the following: \
For **Name**, enter **proxy**. This corresponds to the parameter in the **Endpoint URL**. \
For **Mapped from**, enter **method.request.path.proxy**. \
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-character-error \
(not sure if this helps)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if this will work, but you are probably wanting to change that {s3} pathParam to a {proxy+} which transforms that pathParam into a /'*' wildcard.
See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-settings-method-request.html
Good luck!